# Find maximum visit-able nodes in matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures

I had faced this problem in a coding test and could not find an efficient approach.

Given a Matrix A, The rules for movement are as follows :

1. Can only move Right or Down from any element
2. Can only move within the same row or column of element we start from initially.
3. You can only visit or cross an element if its value is lesser than the value of element you start from.

Find total number of elements one can visit, If one starts from an element A(i,j) where i-> row and
j-> column.

Note : You have to print this output for each matrix element.

Input Matrix :
1 2 3
2 3 1
3 1 2

Output:
1 1 3
1 3 1
3 1 1

Explain : from 1 (i=0,j=0) row wise We can not traverse further so visit-able nodes = 1
Also,  column wise it is same. So for (i=0,j=0) max total nodes is 1.

My approach :

Tried a normal solution where from each element we traverse right side and downward elements and find max of both visit-able element counts.
But this is not efficient.
Can somebody tell an efficient way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That approach has repetitions. For instance, when you were computing for `[0][2]` element (that is 3), you already computed for `[1][2]` (that is 1). Try and see if you can reuse information.

Comment: @StutiRastogi: That is not the case here, as you see the 3rd rule. For [1][2] visitable element count is only 1 (itself) as next downward [2][2] element =2 is greater than this.
But for [0][2] visitable count is 3 as [1][2] , [2][2] both are smaller and inclusing itself.
Otherwise i could have used DP.

Comment: "move within the row and column of element we start from intially" —what does it mean?

Comment: @n.m.  It means no zigzag pattern while moving right or down.
So for any node two paths to be considered Downward (same column increasing row) and rightward (same row increasing column).

Comment: I think that would be "moving within same row **or** column".

Comment: @n.m. corrected thanks :)

Comment: @user3364554 I am sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you can't go to the next element if it's smaller than current one, but you are right.

Comment: @user3364554 one idea to reuse information could be to store the value separately foreach direction, so that, when the start number is bigger than the current one, you can pass all the elements that the current number was already able to pass, if it is the same value you just read the number of elements that the current numbers was able to pass and if it is smaller you stop according to the mouvement rules. Begining by the right-down corner we can reuse all information you already computed. does this seem alright for your case ?

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that we can never move past an element greater than the current element, and the values of smaller elements below or to the right of a big element is irrelevant (since when we move past the big element, we'd also be able to move past all smaller elements according to the problem statement).

- For each column, go from the bottom to the top, keeping a stack which will store elements in decreasing order, along with their index (actually we can just store the index, and use that to look up the element in the matrix).
- For each element we visit:

  - Pop elements from the stack until the largest element in the stack is greater than or equal to the current element (or it's empty).
  - The number of cells that can be visited downwards is the distance to top-most element of the stack (or all the cells to the end if the stack is empty).
  - Push that element onto the stack.
- Repeat the above process from right to left, summing the values gotten above.
- Add 1 to everything to include cells visiting themselves.

Since we only do a constant amount of work per cell, the complexity here is `O(rows*columns)`.

Java code for this:

```java
int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3},
                 {2, 3, 1},
                 {3, 1, 2}};
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>(); // stores the index only
int[][] output = new int[array.length][array[0].length];
for (int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) // direction not important
{
    stack.clear();
    for (int j = array[0].length-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        while (!stack.empty() && array[i][stack.peek()] < array[i][j])
            stack.pop();
        int offset;
        if (stack.empty())
            offset = array[0].length;
        else
            offset = stack.peek();
        output[i][j] = offset - j - 1;
        stack.push(j);
    }
}

// same as above, just with indices swapped
for (int i = array[0].length-1; i >= 0; i--) // direction not important
{
    stack.clear();
    for (int j = array.length-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        while (!stack.empty() && array[stack.peek()][i] < array[j][i])
            stack.pop();
        int offset;
        if (stack.empty())
            offset = array.length;
        else
            offset = stack.peek();
        output[j][i] += offset - j - 1;
        stack.push(j);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++)
    output[i][j] += 1;

for (int[] a: output)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/gED1zK).

Comment: Could not verify this for 
1 2 2,
2 2 1,
2 1 2  output should be

1 1 2,
1 2 1,
2 1 1

Comment: @GP007 Fixed. That should be `1 1 2, 1 3 1, 2 1 1`, shouldn't it? (Since the middle element can visit itself, 1 down and 1 right)

Comment: It will be 2 as we have to find max possible of two possible values in both direction. We can move only in one direction. So either right or down adds 1 and 1 for itself.

Comment: @GP007 Shouldn't the middle element in the example in the question then also be 2?

Comment: You are correct. My mistake it will  1 1 2, 1 3 1, 2 1 1

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to optimize your code is by making use of caching, here is one small implementation of the algorithm.

```
    int visited[3][3];
    memset(visited, -1, sizeof(visited));

    int calculateMaxVisitedNode(int x, int y, int visit_count, int r, int c, int valx, int valy)
    {
        if(x>r || y>c)
        {
            return visit_count;
        }
        if(visited[x][y] != -1)
        {
            return visited[x][y];
        }

        int right = 0;
        int down = 0;

        if(A[valx][valy] > A[x][y+1])
        {
            right = f(x,y+1,visit_count+1,r,c,valx,valy);
        }

        if(A[valx][valy] > A[x+1][y])
        {
            down = f(x+1,y,visit_count+1,r,c,valx,valy);
        }

        visited[x][y] = max(right, down);
        return visited[x][y];
    }
```

So here I am caching already visited cells, so no need to traverse through them again. This could reduce your time complexity by significant amount when number of rows and columns are very high.

Comment: That is not right I think, you made the same mistake as in the first comment

Comment: I get your point, you are saying that if passed (0,2) to my method, it would return 2 instead of three right, so that's is what is good about this algorithm...pass in visit_count = 1 instead of 0 and see the magic

Comment: or if you know that the current cell is not taken into consideration then add +1 to the result returned by this method

Comment: But you don't take into account that the next value has to be compared with the very first value and not the current one

Comment: still not good because the value you are caching is for a specific valx and valy and the result depends on them